# Cocos2d IPhone sprite problem

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

The problem is - when i load game on iphone some sprites are shown, some are not, plus CCBitmapFontAtlas labels and CCMenu button are also not visible and when i tap on the place where button have to be - there is no effect. At simulator it worked just fine. What is the reason of such strange situation?
IPad aslo works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more detail, but it could be some issue with your build.  Try cleaning your targets and republishing to make sure that your iPhone device has the exact files you want it to have.  The behavior you describe could come from older versions of image files being used (say, an Atlas sprite going to a frame that used to be blank but has content in the new version).